# In react how do I dynamically set defaultExpanded in ExpansionPanel

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In a React component using Material-UI I have this

```
<ExpansionPanel defaultExpanded>
```

I need defaultExpanded to be set logically (eg: if I have only 1 instance of the component I want to use defaultExpanded.)

I can set a variable named `expanded` based on logic, like

```
expanded = ''
if (logic) {
  expanded = 'defaultExpanded'
}
```

...then use that `expanded` var like so...

```
<ExpansionPanel {expanded} >
```

This explodes - does not compile. I've tried many variations but I've found no way to dynamically set the `defaultExpanded` property of the ExpansionPanel in react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass it as a props var when you call the stateless component who contains the expansion panel. For example:

```
if(Some default expanded logic here)
<ExpansionPanelMenu defaultExpanded />
```

And in the actual component just pass it as props

```
 const { defaultExpanded } = props;
    <ExpansionPanel
    defaultExpanded={defaultExpanded}
  >
```

Answer (score 0):

defaultExpanded is a boolean prop of ExpansionPanel.

So, you can try like below:

```
expanded = false
if (logic) {
expanded = true
}

 <ExpansionPanel defaultExpanded={expanded} >
```

Comment: Both approaches are same.